# Apache HTTP server configuration issue with Apache Tomcat in AWS EC2

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have created following configuration in AWS EC2

1. Application is running in TOmcat server and listening on port 8080
2. I have Apache Web server installed on Same box
3. I have configured Apache Web Server as with HTTPS
4. Application is accessiable using https://www.example.com

but

Application is also accesible as http://www.example.com:8080/

I  dont want people to access my application using port 8080, like above.

How to prevent it, so that https://www.example.com is accessible but http://www.example.com:8080/ should not be accessible

Comment: Change your EC SG to allow traffic only on 443. So other than https nothing will be allowed in.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh, in that case i need to remove 8080 from my SG entry. If i remove the entry .. then web server is not able to forward to 8080. Actually.. my tomcat is not https ..i have only configured apache webserver as https.

Comment: as you mentioned both webserver and tomcat on are on the same SG, then you can configure your webserver to talk to localhost:8080 and in that case you dont need to worry about the SG.